# Is -javaagent supported by java 1.4?

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement where i have to add -javaagent option in a java opts.
Error observed is `Unrecognized option: -javaagent:`
Is -javaagent supported by java 1.4?Or if not is there any other way  out?

Comment: I guess you know but.. 1.4 is unsupported regarding security fixes since 2008 and is 4 versions behind now. A way out would be to upgrade the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The Java API documentation for java.lang.instrument (where the -javaagent option relies to, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) states at the very bottom that it is "Since JDK1.5"

So you can be pretty sure, together with the error message that you received, that the option is not available in Java 1.4.

Other posts on the internet explicitely state that the javaagent is new in Java 5, for example here: http://javahowto.blogspot.ch/2006/07/javaagent-option.html

Answer (score 1):

Nope as transformers added and existing from 1.5